# Skype in Outlook.com in Ubuntu won't work

Tags: skype, chromium, email, webapps, instant-messaging

I wouldn't normally ask a question like this on AskUbuntu - it's more related to web browsers is what some people might say. But, if you read on, you'll see why I'm asking it on this forum:

If I go to Outlook.com in Chromium on Ubuntu and go to Outlook.com then click the messaging icon, the pane shows up. Sure enough, at the bottom, it's connected to Messenger and Google. But, there is no Skype, yet in the People section (arrow next to Outlook -> People) it says it's connected to Skype. Also, if I try doing the same on another laptop (Chrome + XP) it works fine, as with a school netbook (IE10 + Win 7). I've tried using a blank temporary profile in Chromium just to let you know, so it's not to do with extensions. To see if it was to do with the browser, I tried using a "Like Chrome" user agent (instead of chromium/version -> like chrome/version) - this would make sites think I'm using Chrome, and it worked on whatbrowser.org. But still no luck. Any ideas? And does anyone think I should be asking this on a Microsoft forum?

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screen-shots to the question? Since both outlook.com and Skype are from Microsoft, this may be a bug/feature. You have to ask them.

Comment: http://ubuntuone.com/3m5nomr6MGsHezgdx49WoI

Comment: I see exactly the same problem, mainly that Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu show, that Skype is linked in outlook.com, but not in the messaging pane. I move across to a Windows computer and Chrome and Firefox both show Skype as connected in the messaging pane. Interestingly the installation of the Skype plugin does not seem to work either on there webpage. Check: [skype-plugin-installation-page](https://skypewebexperience.skype.com/content/0-0-0/plugin_installation.html#plugin-install-page) I see the message: Your download has started. Please follow the prompts to save and run the Skype plugin ..

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem lies with the Skype Plugin not being installed for your browser. The page from where to load the plugin is:

https://skypewebexperience.skype.com/content/0-0-0/plugin_installation.html#get-started-page

However, after a couple of clicks the message "Your download has started. Please follow the prompts to save and run the Skype plugin" will be displayed but nothing else happens. I looked at the source html and then the javascript:

https://az351254.vo.msecnd.net/3-0-161/assets/javascript/plugin-install-js.min.js

and it appears that plugins are only available for Windows and Mac

SkypeWebPlugin-2.3.12417.17599.msi
SkypeWebPlugin-2.3.12417.17599.pkg

As things stand now there is no solution to the problem of Skype Messaging not being available on outlook.com.